# Error in downloading jquery library after deploying an application to Azure Web App Virtual Directory

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I created a Web App in Azure and 2 virtual Directories inside it. when i deploy my application to Web App Virtual directory, it throws 404 for JQuery libraries. Lets say for downloading inline.bundle.js it access this URL.
    https://exampleui.ase01.p.azurewebsites.net/inline.bundle.js

But since i have deployed my application in virtual directory my WebApp the scripts are present in that particular directory. Lets say name of my virtual Directory is dev, so the scripts are present in:
     https://exampleui.ase01.p.azurewebsites.net/dev/inline.bundle.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's better to use relative paths which just have the path relative to the HTML file.

```
<script src="path/to/inline.bundle.js"></script>
```

Note that you shouldn't put `/` at the beginning of the js path.

Comment: I am able to solve this by setting Base-href  property while building the application using the command-
ng build --base-href "/dev/" 
but the problem in this case is i am not able to choose environment while building the Application.
 eg. I want to set both dev environment and base-href but only one gets changed in the package.
nh build --env=dev --base-href="/dev/"